# output error in php json-decode

Tags: php, json

my php code generate a non-Valid json output error

my php code :

```
$questions = array();
while($question = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$questions[] = array('question'=> $question);
}
print_r ($questions);

$newQuestions = array('questions' => array());

foreach($questions as $key => $question){
    $newQuestion = array(
            'question' => $question['question']['question'],
            'correct' => $question['question']['correct'],
            'answers' => array(
                    $question['question']['answer1'],
                    $question['question']['answer2'],
                    $question['question']['answer3'],
                    $question['question']['answer4']
                )
    );

    $newQuestions['questions'][] = $newQuestion;

}

$output = json_encode(($newQuestions),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

echo '<br/><br/>';
echo $output;
```

table fields :

```
Question :
correct  :
answer 1 :
answer 2 :
answer 3 :
answer 4 :
```

Example :

```
Question : is php a good language ?
correct  : 1
answer 1 : yes
answer 2 : no
answer 3 : maybe
answer 4 : good
```

the output is OK, and formated as I want.

output sample : http://pastebin.com/eefS7KYW

I am sure my php code is correct but I don't know where is exactly the issue !!

==============
Fixed : it was just two echo $output !

Comment: `json_encode` works fine. The issue must be in your code, but I cannot see what exactly from handpainted screenshots. It would seem you're outputting the result twice.

Comment: looks like its missing a comma

Comment: @RicardoE as `questions` is the only key in the root object it's more likely a double print, otherwise it wouldn't appear right after the 'exception' line.

Comment: @RicardoE json output is missed up in one place only but the whole output is correct and formated properly .

Comment: Just FYI there are other issues with your code. We are long past using `mysql_` functions, use `mysqli` or `pdo` instead. You also use variables needlessly.

Comment: @php_nub_qq i don't  think mysql function is the problem ! because the whole json output are correct except one block that make the json output not valid !!

Comment: I said FYI which stands for "For Your Information", in other words I'm not answering the question, just giving you general advice. If you want help with the question, post an array of questions so I can recreate and test, or better yet create a live demo.

Comment: @php_nub_qq database's fields are : Question,Correct,Question1,Question2,Question3,Question4 ... check the example that I have include !

Comment: I think you mean question, correct, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4?

Comment: Your code is working correctly. If you pay close attention you will notice that the point which you have labelled 'exception' is the json object starting again, which means you are printing it twice, somewhere.

Comment: @nwolybug yes I mean question, correct, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are doing a lot of variable passing which gets very confusing, very quickly. Especially when all the variables are iterations of 'question'. It appears that you are creating an array from information pulled from a database in the format [questions[question,correct,answers[1,2,3,4]]] This code format may work better?

```
   $newQuestions = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $newQuestions['questions'][] = array(
    'question'  =>  $row['question'],
    'correct'   =>  $row['correct'],
    'answers'   =>  array(
        $row['answer1'],
        $row['answer2'],
        $row['answer3'],
        $row['answer4']
        )
    );
}

    $output = json_encode(($newQuestions),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    echo '<br/><br/>';
    echo $output;
```

Had a semicolon in the wrong place.Fixed the code above and test the code with the following:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array('question'=>'Question1',
        'correct'=>3,
        'answer1' => 'Q1Answer1',
        'answer2' => 'Q1Answer2',
        'answer3' => 'Q1Answer3',
        'answer4' => 'Q1Answer4'
    ),
    array('question'=>'Question2',
        'correct'=>3,
        'answer1' => 'Q2Answer1',
        'answer2' => 'Q2Answer2',
        'answer3' => 'Q2Answer3',
        'answer4' => 'Q1Answer4'
    ),
    array('question'=>'Question3',
        'correct'=>3,
        'answer1' => 'Q3Answer1',
        'answer2' => 'Q3Answer2',
        'answer3' => 'Q3Answer3',
        'answer4' => 'Q1Answer4'
    )
);

$newQuestions = array();
//while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
foreach($array as $row){
    $newQuestions['questions'][] = array(
    'question'  =>  $row['question'],
    'correct'   =>  $row['correct'],
    'answers'   =>  array(
        $row['answer1'],
        $row['answer2'],
        $row['answer3'],
        $row['answer4']
        )
    );
}

print_r($newQuestions);
$output = json_encode(($newQuestions),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

echo '<br/><br/>';
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Had a semicolon in the wrong spot. Tested and fixed.

Comment: it works ! thank you ! it was just twice echo that print 2 output :D